# Is it natural to say "my electric bill is paid" when you are reporting a bill's status?

Tags: word-choice, present-tense

Can you please tell me if it's natura and correct to say *my electric bill is paid* when you are telling someone it's current status, not that it's regularly paid.

If doesn't sound natural, I would like to know what you would say instead.

Comment: It's what I would say. Quite natural. We can discuss the current status of a bill (e.g. due, paid, outstanding, etc) using the present tense.